# Orchard CMS - how to sync production and local dashboard project changes

Tags: ftp, orchardcms

If one has a locally built Orchard CMS -- built intentionally from the full source code so I can write my own extensions / make my own alterations -- does this mean I can never make dashboard changes to the site via the published production running instance?

The problem is that if I install a module (or 10 or 100) or a theme via the production site online, those are not then reflected in my local copy, so how would the two get synced up? So is the answer a no-brainer "of course you can't"? But that means never being able to avail yourself of the simplicity of simply jumping on any browser (such as when on a trip, etc) to make changes when need be (there are of course many things such as editing content that simply makes changes to the database, that is not my concern).

Or is there indeed a simple way to sync the local and remote source (via ftp I'm sure, syncing from remote to local in this case), if and when I make changes via the production instance? If so, what pre-requisites are there, for instance, must I turn of pre-compliation for that to work? Or are the options *strictly* two: 1) Always work from local copy and publish changes from there (*always*), or 2) *Always* work from production/non-local instance, but that means actually you don't / cannot even have a local instance?

p.s. this is published as an azure website shared, and I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 (not webmatrix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell, the good practice is to make the code changes on your dev box, and the data changes in production. Add to that source control and database backups for rollback-ability and disaster recovery. We are going to improve on that story soon by enabling for data staging, but for now this is the best practice. So:

1. never install modules in production (this is a code change, so should be done on dev). Of course *enabling* the module has to be done in production once its correct behavior has been verified in dev or staging.
2. Update the site's data on prod, unless you are willing to export/import that data between the sites.
3. Do use the draft (save vs. publish buttons) feature to prepare new versions of contents.
4. Periodically restore the prod database onto your dev box, in order to work with reasonably recent data in dev.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, I guess that settles it. To the dev box we will go (and stay).

Comment: But how do you prevent from overwriting data in prod that you dont want to come deployment time? I have a custom module that writes to the database, and so a migration to production as you suggest means I need to script out the changes that were made from the modules installed in dev (or perhaps use some sql diff/migration tool?), so I can effectively do a merge w/prod. unless i'm missing something in what you are saying?

Comment: What overwriting? Don't do merges of data. When you deploy from dev to prod, the migration will run on prod on the first request.